I am having trouble installing the C# extension using the VSIX file
I need to install Visual Studio Code and a few extensions on a computer with no internet access, I have already installed the .NET Install Tool and (after failing to install the basic C# extension) the C# Dev Kit, but when installing the C# extension I get the error “Extract: not enough bytes in the stream. expected 18139160. got only 17280742”.
What can this error be related to?

Run a disk check on the computer to ensure there are no issues with the storage medium.
